# How to declare new fields in array

Tags: java, arrays, field

My transport class looks like that:

```
private long fromTimestamp;
private long toTimestamp;
private Integer variableId;
private Integer typeId;
private boolean time;
private String period;
private Object[] columns = {variableId, typeId, time, period};
```

Class is used as a RequestBody in my Controller and I do not need fields variableId, typeId, time and period. It should be only in an array.

It has no sense when I put parameters in JSON like that:

```
{
"fromTimestamp": 0,
"toTimestamp": 10,
"variableId": 1, 
"typeId": 1, 
"time": false, 
"period": null,
"columns": [{
    "variableId": 1, 
    "typeId": 1, 
    "time": false, 
    "period": null
}]
```

What should I do to declare new filds directly in array called columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
public class Transport {
    private long fromTimestamp;
    private long toTimestamp;
    private Column[] column;
    ...
}

public class Column {
    private Integer variableId;
    private Integer typeId;
    private boolean time;
    private String period;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay but what's next? How to add it into JSON in Controller?

Comment: You want to serialize this into JSON? What are you using now? There are many libraries you could use to do this and one of them is Jackson. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.